# apache camel aggregator2 - how do I aggregate one of each of two message types?

Tags: apache-camel, aggregator

I have two types of messages (A and B) arriving at an aggregator.  How do I aggregate the first A to arrive with the first B to arrive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you got the EIP book or Camel in Action book, then read the theory about the Aggregator EIP. That would tell you a lot. The aggregate EIP is one of the most complicated EIPs and thus worth while to spent a bit time studying the pattern.

In a nutshel you need to correlate A and B so the aggregate EIP will match the 2 messages, and aggregate them.

So you need to implement how this correlation works as an expression, in Camel you implement this for example using a method call expression, which allows you to use Java code in a method call to determine this.

The outcome of the method should be a String that dictates a correlation group identifier. Then the first A and first B messages should have the same correlation group identifier. Eg so your match messages into groups.

I suggest to study the EIP a bit more, and then think how you can write that correlation logic. Then you can implement that in Java code, and then use a method call expression with the Camel aggregator.

Also what should happen with the 2nd A, 3rd A, and 2nd B, and 3rd B messages? How should they be correlated?

Should it be like

```
1A + 1B
2A + 2B
3A + 3B
```

And then the messages can arrive in any order to the aggregate EIP pattern such as

```
  1B
  2B
  1A
  3B
  2A
  3A
```

And the outcome of the aggregator would be as shown above with 1A+1B ... ?